# iOS: identify line number where exception occurs in stack trace?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, flurry

The stack trace below was captured by Flurry, but it doesn't show the line numbers in our code where the exception gets triggered. Is there a way to infer the line numbers based on this data here, or otherwise gain greater insight into where the issue occurs? As it is, the stack trace leaves little actionable data to debug.

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x1820ede48 <redacted> + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x19282c0e4 _objc_exception_throw + 60
2   UIKit                               0x186bb2a40 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3376
3   UIKit                               0x186bb48dc <redacted> + 120
4   UIKit                               0x18698a0b4 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 216
5   CustomApp                                0x1000bd78c __mh_execute_header + 628620
6   CustomApp                                0x10004aa4c __mh_execute_header + 158284
7   CustomApp                                0x100048cf4 __mh_execute_header + 150772
8   UIKit                               0x1868d10f8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
9   UIKit                               0x1868ba22c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 612
10  UIKit                               0x1868d0a94 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 592
11  UIKit                               0x1868d0720 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 700
12  UIKit                               0x1868c9c74 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 684
13  UIKit                               0x18689d38c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 264
14  UIKit                               0x186b3c1b4 <redacted> + 14992
15  UIKit                               0x18689b8f4 <redacted> + 1616
16  CoreFoundation                      0x1820a60e8 <redacted> + 24
17  CoreFoundation                      0x1820a538c <redacted> + 264
18  CoreFoundation                      0x1820a343c <redacted> + 712
19  CoreFoundation                      0x181fd11f4 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
20  GraphicsServices                    0x18b15f5a4 _GSEventRunModal + 168
21  UIKit                               0x186902784 _UIApplicationMain + 1488
22  CustomApp                                0x100057400 __mh_execute_header + 209920
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x192e9aa08 <redacted> + 4
```